# Problems converting PDF with transparency to EPS

Tags: inkscape, pdf, transparency, eps, file-conversion

I'm having a problem converting PDF files to EPS. I have to do it with three PDF files, each of which has a single-page image. Such image was composed by figures and images on PowerPoint. I did it well with one of the PDFs, but I can not get the same results for the 2 remaining.

The problem is that the only one that was sucessful does not have transparent images. The remaining have transparent images that are really blurry in the generated EPS files.

I originally did it through Inkscape but also tried through the command line:

`pdftops -eps filename.pdf`

Do you know any other option or library I should check for transparent images to work?

I really need the EPS to be editable, not a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postscript does not support transparency, except in some extensions that aim to create PDF files (Distiller and GhostScript). Therefore you need to use the transparency flattener. This can result in rasterized output that may be blurry if the setting is for low res. You can adjust the settings or do the flattening before saving.

You can also adjust the accuracy of the flattener, so that it tries to do more work. That may or may not help